# Low battery indicator doesn't work on batteries but works with trim

Tags: batteries, indicator

I made low battery indicator with LM393. But circuit doesn't work as it should.
If I connect 100k trim to IN- of 1st op amp which imitate "battery voltage", op amp turns red LED on when voltage from 100k trim is less than threshold voltage.
But if I connect + pole from battery to IN- then circuit doesn't work. Why?
Everything is connected on same ground potantial. I use 5V from step-up converter for LM393 VCC.

[image: Schematic with battery]

[image: Schematic with 100k trim as battery]

Comment: Where do you connect the minus side of the battery?

Comment: people that put ground connections upside down at top of schematic should be banned

Comment: @zeta-band Nowhere. I thought that was a problem but I have no idea where I should connect - pole. I thought it'll work because GND of LM393 is connected to step-up GND and step-up GND is connected to - pole of the battery

Comment: You should redraw this circuit including the battery and voltage regulators.

Comment: @SilvioCro Connect the minus terminal of the battery to ground.

Comment: You should also redraw the circuit showing the LM393 as two comparators, rather than as a mystery block. (And if you insist on leaving it as a mystery block, put pin numbers around the block!)

Comment: @PeterBennett LM393 is dual op amp. I was in hurry so I used 1st schematic I found on EasyEDA. Btw, thanks for the advice!

Comment: @SilvioCro: the LM393 is a dual comparator, not a dual op-amp.  The schematic symbol for an op-amp and a comparator is the same, but the functions are quite different.  Using the correct schematic symbol makes it much easier for readers to understand your circuit.

Comment: @zeta-band I connected - pole of the battery to GND of LM393 and problem is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a pull-up resistor of 10 K from the pin 1 to VCC. LM393 has open collector output, cannot drive high by itself.

Later edit , the battery voltage is arround 4V which is out of the common mode range of LM393 with 5V supply (0..3V). Use a divider like in the schematic below or use the 100k pot that you used for tests to bring the voltage in the allowed range.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG8cy0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work.

Comment: @SilvioCro the battery voltage is under 3.5V? For 5V supply voltage this is the maximum common mode input

Comment: Battery voltage is around 4V, I increased threshold voltage above 4V.

Comment: Oh.. then is over the specifications , see the datasheet, page 7, for 5V it's even worse , it works only up to 3.0V . Use a divider to bring-it in the acceptable range, I will put a schematic in the answer

Comment: Datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm393-n.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the anwser!
It's LiIon battery. But I'm not sure does it'll work in real life conditions. When battery is full, what voltage should be on IN- pin? That's confusing me.

Comment: Half vith these values, 2.1V

Comment: So then 2.1V as battery voltage and 1.8V as threshold voltage? Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Also half of the initial thresold voltage, 2v if you want the led to change at 4V

Comment: @SilvioCro With a refference voltage and some slight changes you can supply the circuit from the battery without a step-up converter.

Comment: I use step-up for Arduino, so why not use it for LM393?